# Concentrating a category type using their associated numeric values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
   Col_1 Col_2 Col_3   Type
0    500   659   700    Red
1   1000   450   660    Red
2    800   800   915  Green
3    702   655  1050  Green
4    812   805   915  Green
5    522   555   815  Green
6    900   800   415    Red
7    550   450   515    Red
8    632   205   515    Red
9    760   900   715  Green
10   750   855  1015  Green
11   512   505   615    Red
```

I am trying to set ranges on the 3 numeric columns in a way such that the ranges concentrate as much of type red within their ranges as possible with as little overlap with Green as possible.

So for example, I'm hoping for a solution that recommends something like:

```
    Col_1: 500<=x<=600
    Col_2: 600<=x<=700
    Col_3: 500<=x<=750

yields a 67% concentration of Reds in their range which is the maximum possible concentration of Reds possible using the 3 numeric columns.
```

My current method to do this was to run a decision tree on my data to see what cut-offs it recommends to split the Reds as much away from the Greens as possible.

But I was wondering if there was a For Loop or some other solution that would try different range bands in maybe increments of 25 on the 3 different numeric columns to try to maximize the concentration of Reds in specific ranges of Col 1,2 and 3 similar to the example above and would yield the maximum %age concentration of reds possible using ranges in the 3 columns while keeping the %age concentration of greens to a minimum (so we dont end up with the entire original dataset with 100% reds).

As a value function, it would mean that the %age composition of the Reds in the dataset that results from implementing the ranges on the 3 columns would have the maximum possible %age composition of reds possible while keeping the greens as a %age composition in the resulting dataset to a minimum. This way the function wont return a dataset that's just 100% Reds and 100% greens but one that's more like 70% reds and 30% greens.

Code to recreate the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['500','659','700', 'Red'], ['1000','450','660',  'Red'], ['800','800','915',  'Green'],
        ['702','655','1050',  'Green'], ['812','805','915',  'Green'], ['522','555','815',  'Green'],
        ['900','800','415', 'Red'], ['550','450','515',  'Red'], ['632','205','515',  'Red'],
        ['760','900','715',  'Green'],['750','855','1015',  'Green'],['512','505','615',  'Red']] 


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Col_1','Col_2','Col_3', 'Type'])
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to specify more parameter(s): you say you're trying to maximise concentration/ratio of Red:Green.  What if your code spits out an answer: `Col_1 rng: 500 <= x <= 500; Col_2 rng: 659 <= x <= 659; Col_3 rng: 700 <= x <= 700; yields 100% concentration in each column`?

Comment: Something like "can you more clearly specify a value function?"

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp Yea, ideally a the function would try to get the maximum reds in it's range as a % composition of the resulting dataset while keeping the greens as a % composition in it's resulting dataset low.  So it doesn't just default to 100% on both. Let me add some more clarity around that.

Comment: Do you have a minimum range width? Or a minimum "count" of Reds/maximum count of Greens? Or are you trying to maximise "number of Reds contained in variable range, given ratio of Red:Green cannot exceed (given %)?"

Comment: For example, by inspection, using the ranges `Col_1: [500,700], Col_2: [200,510], Col_3: [410,700]` gives `[Col_1: 80% (4 Red, 1 Green), Col_2: 100% (4 Red 0 Green), Col_3: 100% (6 Red 0 Green)]`

Comment: "Or are you trying to maximise "number of Reds contained in variable range, given ratio of Red:Green cannot exceed (given %)?" - Yes, this exactly. I made the dataset with random values to illustrate the problem but in this case the last 2 solutions you showed would be the correct ranges for me to use since they minimize the %age composition of Greens while maximizing the %composition of Reds. In my actual data, the % composition of greens would always be the majority. I would want to minimize it as much as possible. I can use a threshold like you said: Green cannot exceed (given %)